# Jquery combining show/hide with slideToggle script

Tags: slidetoggle

I have 2 scripts that I am using and I would like to combine them into 1 but I haven't been successful so I would appreciate some help if possible. The first script is a show/hide when pressing a Expand all and collapse all button:

```
    $(".hide").click(function(){
$(".screentitle").hide();
});
$(".show").click(function(){
$(".screentitle").show();
});
```

The second code I use is the image swap for slideToggle:

```
    $(".chaptertitle").live("click", function(){
$(".screentitle", this).slideToggle("fast");
var $img = $(".img-swap", this);
    if ($img.attr('src').indexOf("plus.png") > -1) {
    $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace('plus', 'minus'));
return false;
    } else {
    $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace('minus', 'plus'));
```